# If $f$ is continuous and $I$ compact, is $f^{-1}(I)$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $f:E\to F$ where $E$ and $F$ are metric space. We suppose $f$ continuous. I know that if $I\subset E$ is compact, then $f(I)$ is also compact. But if $J\subset F$ is compact, do we also have that $f^{-1}(J)$ is compact ?

If yes and if $E$ and $F$ are not necessarily compact, it still works ?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=1$ on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: functions which satisfied this kind of properties are known as proper map

Comment: Every constant function is continuous and has a compact image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not necessarily; consider $f:(-2\pi,2\pi)\to[-1,1]$ given by $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Comment: The continuous image of a compact space is compact. Since any  non-empty space can be continuously mapped onto a one-point space, we mut be more careful about inverses.

Answer (score 3):

Clayton's answer based on non-injectivity is very good. However, we can also base a counterexample on non-surjectivity.

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto[-1,1]$ given by
$$
f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}
$$
Then
$$
f^{-1}([-1,1])=\mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: Sir, in your example, what is inverse image of $1$ under $f$? I mean is there exists some $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that, $f(a) =1$?

Comment: This is the whole point of the "non-surjectivity" that was mentioned. There are no points $x$ so that $f(x)=\pm1$. That is, $f^{-1}(\{-1,1\})=\varnothing$. This means $f^{-1}([-1,1])=f^{-1}((-1,1))=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sir thank you for your quick reply, got it. $f^{-1}([-1, 1]) =\{x\in\mathbb{R} : f(x)\in [-1, 1]\}$ hence $f^{-1}([-1, 1]) =\mathbb{R}$